# Recreating "ABPeoplePicker" functionality on Mac

Tags: xcode, cocoa, abaddressbook

I'm trying to create a Mac version of an iPhone app, and specifically I need to be able to pick a person from the user's Address Book, akin to the ABPeoplePicker on iOS.  The look of the interface isn't particularly important (be it a separate popup window or a subview etc), I just need to pull up a list from Address Book and have the user select a row, and then feed the First and Last names from that contact back into my code.

But from what I can tell, that functionality doesn't exist for Mac, or else it isn't nearly as user-friendly and intuitive to implement.

Can anyone shed any light on how I might do this?  Are there built-in functions I haven't found yet, or any good 3rd party code sources you can recommend?

PS  I know enough to be dangerous, but I'm still very much a beginner.  Code samples and tutorial links are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps Apple's [CocoaPeoplePicker](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CocoaPeoplePicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003159) demo can help you.

Here's the [AddressBook](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/AddressBookC_Collection/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003856) framework reference

Comment: Thank you!  I've implemented the CocoaPeoplePicker on a secondary window, it's exactly what I need.